# Stripe Add Usage with PHP CURL

Tags: php, api, curl, strip

Hi I am adding a usage to a customer but I am getting the following error:

```
{
  "error": {
    "code": "parameter_unknown",
    "doc_url": "https://stripe.com/docs/error-codes/parameter-unknown",
    "message": "Received unknown parameter: {\"quantity\":1,\"timestamp\":1624294464}",
    "param": "{\"quantity\":1,\"timestamp\":1624294464}",
    "type": "invalid_request_error"
  }
}
```

Which is weird because `quantity` && `timestamp` are required params in the request.

This is the code I have right now.

Note: I am working with laravel but I don't want to use the php library.

```
$url = 'https://api.stripe.com/v1/subscription_items/'.$subscriptionItemObj->stripe_id.'/usage_records';
$fields = ["quantity"=>1, "timestamp" => $dt->getTimestamp()];
$fieldsEncoded = json_encode($fields);
$headers  = [ 'Authorization: Bearer '.env('STRIPE_SECRET') ];

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $fieldsEncoded);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);

$output = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
```

Do you know why this could be happening?

Answer (score 0):

You are encoding post parameters as json. Just pass it like `param1=val1&param2=val2`

```
 $fields = 'quantity=1&timestamp='.$dt->getTimestamp();
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $fields);
```

Refer [php.net](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php)

[image]